# Call a method on Onload in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

**I need to call handleSelectionChange method on Onload but while doing that it throws the error as mentioned in the screenshot below.If I dont call it in connectedCallback method then it works fine. Please help!**

[image]

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.handleSelectionChange();
    
    const response = {};
    Promise.all([
      getCoverageList().then((data) => (response.coveragesMap = data)),
      getProducts().then((data) => (response.productsMap = data))
    ]).then(() => {
      this.setCoverageOptions(response.coveragesMap);
      this.setProductOptions(response.productsMap);

      if (this.productId && this.coverageId) {
        this.setClausesData(this.productId, this.coverageId);
      }
    });
  } 

handleSelectionChange(event) {
    const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
    this.data.forEach((item) => (item.selected = false));
    selectedRows.forEach((item) => (item.selected = true));
  
    this.updateSelection();

  }
```

**In the image below I have two rows selected but they are not visible on my applies to table.**

[image]

**After I select the 3rd row it shows all three in the table.So I want those two rows to be displayed in the table on Onload.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you manually call `handleSelectionChange`, you have not passed any param to the method, that is why `event` is undefined, and you see that error.

And when you might be triggering it with `onClick` or `onChange` it will have the mouse event binded with it so the event will have a object and it will work fine. You can trigger an `onChange` or `onClick` programmatically from `connectedCallback` which will have the event binded and it should work.

Like this `this.template.querySelector('input').click();`

You can fetch the selected rows by this `this.template.querySelector('your lwc class name / markup name').getSelectedRows()`

Comment: But my doubt is , why to call that in `connectedCallback`?

Comment: You can't interact with DOM objects before the afterRender handler, including during an onload or constructor call, if any. connectedCallback happens after afterRender, so you can then work with the DOM normally.

Comment: @NagendraSingh I have edited the question I hope that will clear your doubt. Please suggest if you have anything to make it work.

Comment: Ok you just wanted selected rows, I have updated my answer

Comment: Okay so in place of ```event.detail.selectedRows``` I should use ```this.template.querySelector('your lwc class name / markup name').getSelectedRows()``` to make it work, right?